# Derivation for average value input current in buck-boost converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, math, modeling

I am struggling with the derivation of average value of input current as below.
The image is from the lecture [here](http://ecee.colorado.edu/copec/book/slides/Ch7slide.pdf) (page 26).

Here is what I got so far.
How did the lecture derive the final step here?

$$ \langle i_g(t)\rangle_{T_s}=\frac{1}{T_s} \int_{0}^{T_s} i_g(t) dt =\frac{1}{T_s} \int_{0}^{dT_s} \langle i(t)\rangle_{T_s}  dt = d(t)\langle i(t)\rangle_{T_s} $$

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$ \langle i_g(t)\rangle_{T_s}=\frac{1}{T_s} \int_{0}^{T_s} i_g(t) dt =\frac{1}{T_s} \int_{0}^{dT_s} \langle i(t)\rangle_{T_s}  dt = d(t)\langle i(t)\rangle_{T_s} $$

Lets consider i(t).  Taking the integral of i(t) with respect to t will result in ti(t).  I am assuming also Ts is a subscript in this derivation.  The steps missing would be the following:

$$ \frac{dT_s}{T_s}i(t)_{Ts} - \frac{0}{T_s}i(t)_{Ts} = d(t)i(t)_{Ts} $$

d(t) needs to be taken with respect to t which is why it appears in the final derivation.  The computation of the integral is really the only step missing in this case.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. But I think there is a problem with this. The average value <i(t)> is not a constant, right?

Comment: Replace I(t) by y.  It will make more sense to your eyes I believe.  You are not taking the integral in function of dy.  Therefore, I(t) should be treated as a constant I believe.